# dbus-daemon listening on server port

Tags: dbus

I have written a simple server program which listens on port 4849. When I start it the first time everything works fine. If I stop and restart it, it fails:

> Cannot bind!! ([Errno 98] Address already in use)

Netstat tells me this...

```
root@node2:/home/pi/woof# netstat -pl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address  State PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:4849    *:*       LISTEN      2426/dbus-daemon
tcp        0                  *:*       LISTEN      2195/sshd       
....
```

What is dbus-daemon? Do I need it? Why is it listening on the port my server was listening on?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, you do need dbus-daemon. To see all of the services using dbus-daemon you can `sudo busctl list`. See also `sudo busctl --help`. As to the specific problem, you might try capturing the SIGTERM signal, which is usually the signal which stops a process, and make sure your socket is closed within the signal handler.